# Jenkins pipeline keeps and old value for a variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Hello i have the following code in a Jenkinsfile for a declarative pipeline but this has a strange behaviour, e.g:

1. If this job is run by first time the variable 'VERDICT' has some value, e.g: FAIL (which is ok), this variable can has 3 possibles values which are: FAIL PASS, NOT_RUN
2. If this job is run by second time the variable 'VERDICT' keeps the previous value

   ```
   stage('run some code'){
       steps{
           script{
               VERDICT = sh (
                   script: '''#!/bin/bash
                   status=$(python ${SCRIPT})
                   echo ${status}
                   ''', returnStdout: true
               ).trim()
               echo "The VERDICT is: ${VERDICT}"
               if (VERDICT == 'FAIL') {
                   currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
               }
               if (VERDICT == 'PASS') {
                   currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
               }
               if (VERDICT == 'NOT_RUN') {
                   currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
               }
           }
       }
    }
   ```

Any help here would be welcome :)

Comment: Have you ran "#!/bin/bash
                status=$(python ${SCRIPT})
                echo ${status}"   multiple time  (outside jenkins?)

Comment: What would be the expected behavior? What‘s in that python script?

Comment: Yes i’ve ran the python script multiples times outside Jenkins.

Comment: Inside of the python script contains a routine to detect patches from Gerrit that contains python files in order to analyzed with pylint and it trows simples prints in order to catch them with a bash variables

Answer (score 0):

Use 'env' to workaround the issue:

```
tage('run some code'){
steps{
    script{
        env.VERDICT = sh (
            script: '''#!/bin/bash
            status=$(python ${SCRIPT})
            echo ${status}
            ''', returnStdout: true
        ).trim()
        echo "The VERDICT is: ${env.VERDICT}"
        if (env.VERDICT == 'FAIL') {
            currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        }
        if (env.VERDICT == 'PASS') {
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
        }
        if (env.VERDICT == 'NOT_RUN') {
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. when i setup VERDICT as env variable their content is null

Comment: Are you sure that you've added the 'env.' in the first stayement?

Comment: Yes I am very sure

Comment: Very odd - this kind of code worked for me every time I've used it.

Comment: what is the output of 'echo "The VERDICT is: ${env.VERDICT}"' ?

Comment: Well the thing is that this is a part of code that I have, this code usually is being called automatically when a new patch is upload to Gerrit Code Review and in this scenario has the strange behavior, but when I launch the job manually this code works very well, so the issue is when is being triggered automatically :(

Comment: The output of the variable env.VERDICT is always fail

Comment: what is 'always fail' meaning?